# Hash Checking in setup.py install requires

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

According to [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode), it is possible to specify the hash of a requirement in the requirements.txt file.
Is it possible to get the same by specifying the hash in the setup.py so that the hash is checked when someone simply does `pip install <package>`?.
I'm specifying the requirements in the setup.py by passing the  `install_requires` keyword argument to the `setup` function in the distutils package.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(name='<package-name>',
      ...
      ...
      install_requires=['ecdsa==0.13', 'base58==0.2.5']
```

Maybe there is another way to achieve the same but i couldn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I don't believe there is a simple way to specify a hash check within setup.py. My solution around it is to simply use virtualenv with hashed dependencies in requirements.txt. Once installed in the virtual environment you can run **pip setup.py install** and it will check the local environment (which is your virtual environment) and the packages installed is hashed.

Inside **requirements.txt** your hashed packages will look something like this:

```
requests==2.19.1 \
--hash=sha256:63b52e3c866428a224f97cab011de738c36aec0185aa91cfacd418b5d58911d1 \
--hash=sha256:ec22d826a36ed72a7358ff3fe56cbd4ba69dd7a6718ffd450ff0e9df7a47ce6a
```

Activate your virtualenv and install requirements.txt file:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --require-hashes
```